# How can I to do to make workable my datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Hello I have this code but it does not work. Here is my code :

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.strptime("16/02/2020", "%d/%m/%Y")
```

I got this error :

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

How can I have to do to make it workable ?

Thank you bery much !

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code...

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 this is working for me

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.strptime("16/02/2020", "%d/%m/%Y")
print(a)
```

```
2020-02-16 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me.  The line that's producing the error is in some other part of your program.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.datetime.strptime("16/02/2020", "%d/%m/%Y")
>>> print(a)
2020-02-16 00:00:00
```